# Remove a value from a set with a function decorator

Tags: python, wrapper, decorator

Is there a way to remove one item from a set through the use of a decorator?  I have a function to generate all the factors for a number - num, and return a set.  For the problem I am working on, I want to return the set excluding the value - num.  I would like to do it through the use of a decorator, but not sure how.

My factor function in euler.py:

```
def factors(n):    
    return set(reduce(list.__add__, 
               ([i, n//i] for i in range(1, int(n**0.5) + 1) if n % i == 0)))
```

The function I want to decorate:

```
from euler import factors

def remove_last(func, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapper(x):
         func.remove(x)
    return func

factors = remove_last(factors(10)) 
print factors
```

The current output:

```
set([1, 10, 2, 5])
```

The desired output:

```
set([1, 2, 5])
```

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do this with a decorator? It seems straightforward enough to simply have `factors` remove the value itself, and the way you use `remove_last` in your example suggests that you might want an API other than that which decorators provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a decorator that modifies a function which returns a set so that the set returned doesn't have the function arguments:

```
def proper(func):
    def f(*args, **kwargs):
        s = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return s.difference(args)
    return f
```

For example:

```
@proper

def factors(n):    
    return set(reduce(list.__add__, 
               ([i, n//i] for i in range(1, int(n**0.5) + 1) if n % i == 0)))
```

Then:

```
>>> factors(10)
{1, 2, 5}
```

I haven't tested it with a function with more than one argument.